# eclipse does not recognize package

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

(HELIOS Eclipse, m2eclipse is installed from the update site)

I am creating a new web application:  File->New->Other->Maven->Maven Project, Next, Next, then selected maven-archetype-webapp, added a Group Id and Artifact Id. Now in the newly created project I want to add a new java package: right click on , new -> package. Inserted package name and click on finish.

And I'm getting a new folder. Eclipse does not recognize this as a package.

What should I do to make Eclipse recognize that folder as a package?

Many tia,

DHR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `maven-archetype-webapp` does not generate a `src/main/java` folder by default and if you want to add Java sources in your webapp, you need to create `src/main/java` yourself.

Once this directory has been created, **right-click** on your project and then use  **Maven > Update Project Configuration** and it will get added as source directory. Then you'll be able to add sources.

Last thing, either use the maven-eclipse-plugin **or** use m2eclipse, not both, they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thank you for the complete and enlightening answer!

Answer (score 2):

It should work. You can mark the folder containing the package as "source folder" in eclipse, but only as a fast solution...

I usually work with eclipse wihout m2eclipse, and I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate the eclipse project. Maybe you can manually fix this running the command now (from eclipse with the plugin or from mvn directly).

Comment: I did just like you said: run mvn eclipse:eclipse and it solved the problem